# Mysql is looking in much more, estimate rows, then expected

Tags: mysql

I have `user_rates` table where i have two user foreign references user_id_owner and user_id_rated.
This is my create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_rates` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id_owner` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id_rated` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 - dislike, 1 - like',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_rates_user_id_rated_foreign` (`user_id_rated`),
  KEY `user_rates_user_id_owner_foreign` (`user_id_owner`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_rates_user_id_owner_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id_owner`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_rates_user_id_rated_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id_rated`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1825767 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

---

When i execute this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    user_id_rated
FROM
    `user_rates` AS ur
WHERE
    ur.user_id_owner = 10101;
```

It shows estimate rows to examine 107000, but returning only 60000.

Can you explain me why it's examining so many rows, when it is comparing with equality operator and also comparing field is foreign key?

### EDIT

I am getting this on `EXPLAIN`

[image]

I want to add several where clauses also. At last my query looks like this:

```
Explain SELECT 
    user_id_rated
FROM
    `user_rates` AS ur
WHERE
    ur.user_id_owner = 10101
        AND (ur.value IN (1, 2, 3)
        OR (ur.value = 0
        AND ur.created_at > '2020-02-04 00:00:00'));
```

**Output**: 
[image]

It will be nice if query can be more optimized. I don't understand why isn't it reducing estimate rows.

### Steps i tried when optimizing

- Added compose index on (user_id_owner, value, created_at)
  But estimate row is not reducing, It is filtering even more rows [image]

Maybe i am doing indexing wrong? I really don't know how to make proper indexes. Sorry for bad question, I am new here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get when doing `EXPLAIN SELECT 
    user_id_rated
FROM
    user_rates AS ur` without the `WHERE`?

Comment: Do you have a problem with the speed of the query?

Comment: *It shows estimate rows to examine 107000* This value is taken from table statistic and is approximate. Great difference tells that you have analyzed you table long ago (or never). Renew statictic if you really need in the values close to practical ones.

Answer (score 0):

The "rows" is an estimate, often quite far off -- sometimes even worse than your example.  The incorrectness of the estimate rarely impacts performance.

You can run `ANALYZE TABLE tablename` to improve the estimate.  But it may still not be better.

For the *current* query, use:

```
( SELECT  user_id_rated
    FROM  `user_rates` AS ur
    WHERE  ur.user_id_owner = 10101
      AND  ur.value IN (1, 2, 3)
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT  user_id_rated
    FROM  `user_rates` AS ur
    WHERE  ur.user_id_owner = 10101
      AND  ur.value = 0
      AND  ur.created_at > '2020-02-04 00:00:00'
);
```

And have the composite (and "covering") indexes:

```
INDEX(user_id_owner, value, user_id_rated)
INDEX(user_id_owner, value, created_at, user_id_rated)
```

If there are other variations of the query, show us.  As you may guess; the details are important.

(The simplified version of the query does not provide any useful information when discussing the *real* query.)